# Regex to match a specific function call and capture arguments using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to look for a specific function call statement and if found need to extract the arguments using javascript regex.
for ex: say `obj.methodname(arg1,arg2)` or `obj.methodname(arg1, arg2)`
notice the space between the arguments which is possible and the number of arguments is also not fixed.

I tried various regex for the same from SO itself but couldn't get it to work
one of them is `/obj.methodname([\w,]*)/.exec(text)` but not getting the arguments, only getting methodname

please help

Comment: try `obj\.methodname\(([\w\s,]*)\)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like,

```
> "obj.methodname(arg1,arg2)".match(/obj.methodname\((.*)\)/)[1].split(",")
< ["arg1", "arg2"]
```

Further, you can `trim` the values to get rid of the spaces

```
> ["arg1", " arg2"].map(function(value){ return value.trim() })
< ["arg1", "arg2"]
```

Comment: what if i pass a function result: `obj.method( "la (LA)".bold(), 342.43);` ?

Comment: @dandavis that is fine, but this solution will fail if the function call in the argument takes another set of arguments, like `obj.method( "la (LA)".bold(10, 20), 342.43)`. This case is not regular language so we may need a more powerful language to take care of that, and not preferred to be solved using Regex.

Comment: thats ok, it served my purpose, as I know the function call and its possible arguments, and looking for a specific function call